# "object doesn't support this property or method" when using "print"

Tags: forms, vba, excel, printing

I'm kind of new to VBA (using it with Excel) and I'm currently going through some tutorials to get an idea of how it's different to Java oder C#. But that's not the question ... ;-)

This one tutorial tells me to use "Print" in the Form_Initialize-procedure (I'm using Office XP with VBA6 ... don't ask me why, it's not my decision :-P). But when I do so, it gives me the above mentioned error (or at least I guess that the error must read something like this in english, my version is german :D).

Here's what I'm trying to do in an extremely easy example:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Print "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

Following the tutorial, this should print "Hello World" to the "surface" of the form about to be initialized...
Following the help (F1), it should do just about the same...
But it doesn't ;-)

Anybody got any idea where I'm wrong? I don't get it ...

Thanks in advance and greetings
gilaras

**================================UPDATE================================**
The tutorial tells me to write

```
Print " a", "      b", "a*b", "a+b", "Int(a/b)"
```

This should give me a tabular kind of expression on the form.
Is that even possible using a TextBox?

Comment: Somehow I seem not to be allowed to add "Hi there" to the beginning of me post. So...here it is: Hi there :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need insert some kind of control to the user form in which you place your text. E.g. place a control of the type `Caption` and name it `Caption1`(in the properties list <kbd>F4</kbd>).

Then you can assign a value with:

```
Me.Caption1 = "Hello world!"
```

Alternatively, depending on what you need, you can use `Debug.Print "Hello world!"` to simply output the string in the debug console (only helpful during development) - or use `MsgBox "Hello world!"` to show a message to the user. In this case you need no form at all, but simply need to trigger the macro, e.g. from  button in Excel.

Comment: I'm confused. The help to the print-function says (translated freely on the fly :P) "If this method is called in a form-module, the output list is printed to the form itself"
Doesn't that mean what I think it means? :D The tutorials shows screenshots were it does actually work ...

Comment: Please provide a link to this - I'm not aware of such functionality within Excel VBA...

Comment: http://www.vbtutor.net/vb6/lesson11.html

What comes to my mind right now is that is says "vb6" instead of "vba" ... should my superior be wrong telling me that's all I need to know and stating that he did learn his stuff using this tutorial? ;-)

But still; if i put my cursor to the Print statement and press F1, it tells me what I tried to translate in my first comment ...

Comment: Forms & Graphics are different between VB6 & Office VBA, the former uses a "built-in" forms engine whilst Office uses "Microsoft Forms" - which does not support `.Print`.  Anything not involving UI specifics is pretty much the same between the two.

Comment: Well okay then ... in this case, this can't work like I wanted it to ;-) Maybe I should tell my superior ... but in any case I should look for some different tutorials ;-) Thanks for your answers...:-)

Answer (score 1):

VBA not same with Win32 app.
Using print is old version, now is not same. If you want to print something to the surface, you must add a thing to write it. Like...

Add a Textbox(Object) from the Toolbox to the Form,
add a label(object) too
Then your textbox default name is Textbox1 and label default name is Label1

So, on your code :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   textbox1.text = "Hello World"
Label1.text = "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print in the immediate window/console (ctr+g) by using debug.print
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx